# Same equation in Excel and VB.net give different results

Tags: excel, vb.net, math

I have an equation that currently exists in a spreadsheet that I want to include in a program I am writing.  When evaluating the equation in vb.net with the same values as the excel version I get a different answer, but not by a significant margin.

The Excel Equation:

```
=((3*H14)/(4*H13^2))*(((H11^2)-(2*(H12^2)))+((H12^4)-8*(H12^4)*LN(H11/H12)+(2*H11^2*H12^2))/(H11^2+(2*(H12^2))))

H11=a; H12=b; H13=t; H14=P
```

The vb.net equation:

```
    Stress = ((3 * P) / (4 * thk ^ 2)) * ((a ^ 2 - 2 * b ^ 2) + (b ^ 4 - 8 * b ^ 4 * Log(a / b) + (2 * a ^ 2 * b ^ 2)) / (a ^ 2 + 2 ^ b ^ 2))
```

With a=7.125; b=1.5; t=1.25; P=595

The Excel value = 14094.066

The vb.net value = 14041.618

Can anyone point to why the answers would be different?

Comment: What are the types of the variables?

Comment: a, b, and t are double. P is integer

Comment: Don't expect us to debug this for you. Instead, break it down into chunks (different intermediate cells in Excel, different intermediate variables in VBA) and figure out where they're diverging. You can do that much more easily with your existing sheet and code than we can.

Comment: Have you considered how floating point arithmetic could be contributing to the discrepancy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formulas are different in the last term

Compare

```
(H11^2+(2*(H12^2))))
         ^
```

to

```
(a ^ 2 + 2 ^ b ^ 2))
           ^
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to rounding errors since that is a very long expression. Excel's precision is somewhat less than the double used for math in .net

Checkout this

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/78113/floating-point-arithmetic-may-give-inaccurate-results-in-excel

vs

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/921a8ffc-9829-4145-bdc9-a96c1ec174a5/decimal-vs-double-difference?forum=csharpgeneral